# Access to methods in web inspector on svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In a app developed in svelte i use maplibre (but same applies to mapbox). I create a map and everything is OK

```
 import { Map, NavigationControl, Popup, LngLat,Marker } from "maplibre-gl";
 let map;
 onMount(() => {
   map = new Map({
```

... etc

When visualizing the app I want to access to the map properties and methods (map.getStyle(), map.getZoom() etc) using the web inspector, but i just get an error message (example)
map.getZoom is not a function

I assume this is not exclusive of mapbox library but a Svelte (configuration?) issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Svelte does not pollute the global scope.

If you want to access values directly for debugging purposes, use the dev tools debugger. I.e. set breakpoints where the values are created or in event handlers. (This requires either setting the breakpoints in the compiled output or having source maps configured.)

You can manually set value in the global scope, though I would not recommend this, if anything, only do so in the development build. E.g. set `window._map` in `onMount`.

If you `console.log` an object, dev tools also commonly offer an option to store the value in a temporary variable via the context menu.